# Linq return result as list

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hi I am stuck with return the linq result as list. I try to convert but failed to return as the list. Below is my code. Please help. Thanks

```
Public Function GetConfigList(ByVal aConfig As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION) As List(Of Config)
    Dim Data = From p In Db.TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION _
               Select p

    If Data IsNot Nothing Then
        ConvertGeneralConfig(Data)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Private Function ConvertGeneralConfig(ByVal aConfig As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION) As List(Of Config)

        Dim pConfig As New Config
        pConfig.ConfigID = aConfig.INTERNAL_NUM
        pConfig.ConfigType = aConfig.CONFIG_TYPE
        pConfig.ConfigName = aConfig.CONFIG_NAME
        pConfig.ConfigValue = aConfig.CONFIG_VALUE

        Return pConfig
    End Function
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? From the looks of your code it's either that you're returning a single `Config` item from `ConvertGeneralConfig`, or that your `Data` variable will be a query result and thus not compatible with your method signature. But since your code would not compile as-is, it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 0):

If you only expect one result - then use `First()` or a [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim Data = (From p In Db.TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION _
           Select p)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

your `Data` now only contains the first element of the result. If none was found `Data` is nothing.

**UPDATE**

If you want your function to return a list then you have to *create* a list, and return it:

```
Private Function ConvertGeneralConfig(ByVal aConfig As TT_GENERAL_CONFIGURATION) As List(Of Config)

        Dim pConfig As New Config
        pConfig.ConfigID = aConfig.INTERNAL_NUM
        pConfig.ConfigType = aConfig.CONFIG_TYPE
        pConfig.ConfigName = aConfig.CONFIG_NAME
        pConfig.ConfigValue = aConfig.CONFIG_VALUE

        Dim lst As New List(Of Config) 'Creates a list
        lst.Add(pConfig) ' add the object to the list
        Return lst  ' returns the list


    End Function
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. What I have to do if I want expect more that single result of the first function above ? then pass in to the second function to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might want to use

```
If Data IsNot Nothing Then
    Return ConvertGeneralConfig(Data)
Else
    Return Nothing
End If
```